# write into file by changing the file to rtf - awk

Tags: shell, awk, converters, rtf

i am stumbling over one thing:

i am sorting a bunch of files in awk and saving the sorted particles as txt. but now i need to save them as .doc and especially in landscape format. i googled a lot and found out that the only way of doing this is save the file as doc but during creating the file, write these `rtf code` into file and then write the real content into file.

rtf start-tag code:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0 {\fonttbl {\f0 Courier;}}
{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;}
\landscape
\paperw15840\paperh12240\margl720\margr720\margt720\margb720
```

and rtf close-tag:

```
}
```

the close tag will be written after the last line of the file as the last line into the new created file.

my problem is, how can i find the last line of the file inside the awk before coming to `END`.

this is my code. http://pastebin.com/mfjH4NYY
 it is huge code to know what is happenning, but the point is: the `fnnID` is not available in the `END` tag, thru this, a new file will be created if i try to append the `}` char to close the rtf format. can someone help me figure out the clue?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you'll have a function `write_header(filepath)` that will write the RTF header into a file. Make this function record in some global variable all the `filepath`s it was passed. Then, in your END, loop over these `filepath`s and write the RTF footer into them.

As for your new "ls -l" question: I don't see why you need to use it.

Here's what I suggested:

```
function write_header(filepath) {
  print "{\\rtf1\\ans .... " >> filepath
  tracked[max_header++] = filepath
}

BEGIN {
  # You don't have to write the headers in BEGIN. Just make sure it's the
  # first thing you write to the files.
  write_header("file1.doc")
  write_header("file2.doc")
  write_header("another_file.doc")
}

END {
  # Write the footers.
  for(i in tracked) {
    print "}" >> tracked[i]
  }
}
```

Comment: oh okay, so in the ``END`` i will loop over the files and insert the rtf close tag to each of them. but how can i ``ls -l`` inside the awk ?